# .pac files for ubuntu - command line

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, docker

I'm in an environment that uses complex proxy settings and uses .pac file to describe/resolve them. I want to setup some VM's and docker containers on this environment mainly based on ubuntu. The typical "system --> preferences --> network proxy --> apply system wide" answer doesn't help a lot because I don't have access to the UI. Ideally a solution would apply really system-wide i.e. work with `curl`, `wget`, `apt-get`, `pip` and `maven`. Is there such solution?

Answer (score 6):

From command line there is no option for setting "system wide" proxy, you must set variables in several files depeding on application user.

**Almost all command line applications**

Edit `/etc/environment`

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/
https_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
ftp_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/   
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:port/  
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:port/  
FTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy:port/  
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

**WGET**

Edit `/etc/wgetrc`

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
https_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/    
ftp_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port/
```

**APT**

Edit or create `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxy`

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:password@proxy:port/";    
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:password@proxy:port/";   
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:password@proxy:port/";
```

**CURL**

Edit or create in your home `~/.curl.rc`

```
proxy = user:password@proxy:port
```

**PIP**

I didn't find a complete solution for PIP, so I'd rather recommend to use pip with command variable `--proxy`

```
pip --proxy <proxy> install <module>
```

**MAVEN**

I've never used maven although I've found [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Hopes it helps you.

Comment: in the case of the curl the filename is ~/.curlrc

Comment: this does not discuss the case of a .pac file